# How to build publish shared library project in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)
>   [Export android library project for reuse without source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075760/export-android-library-project-for-reuse-without-source-code)

Does anybody know any examples how to publish library project? I'm looking for information how can I publish my library project which contains code, layouts and activities without publishing the source code.

Comment: Yes, creating jar file from sources is one thing, but that does not cover any other stuff like layouts, styles and so on.

Comment: If you take the time to actually read the SO answer I linked to, you will notice that it covers packaging resources.

Comment: Yes, I read the link you posted, but that method exposes all the other stuff than the source code. Perhaps it's misleading to use "source" term when discussing layouts and styles.

Comment: "that method exposes all the other stuff than the source code" -- you have no choice about that. Note that "all the other stuff" is world readable on the devices anyway.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. I didn't know that it's not possible publish resources without exposing them.

Answer (score 1):

creating library >>

1) Create android project in Eclipse,

2) enter Project Properties -> Android and check isLibrary property. Now you can add this library to you Application project by adding it to list on the same property page.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

for creating jar file>>

In Eclipse, you can use the "export" option on the project to create a jar file. This will open the JAR creation wizard.

Comment: Yes, creating jar file from sources is one thing, but that does not cover any other stuff like layouts, styled and so on.